# PHP Returns 500, only when posted with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Hello,**

I'm working on a two step authentication part of a website, and like to check it with an AJAX post. However, the AJAX post will always return a 500 Error. When I run the code which the AJAX posts to, it seems to work. Why is that?

**ajax.php?action=startauth**

```
       session_start();

        $username = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
        $auth = htmlentities($_POST['auth']);

        // Get User Information
        $get_userdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$username."'");
        $userdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_userdata);

        // Get the Secret and save this
        $secret = $userdata['auth_secret'];

        // Initiate the Library
        require_once ('twostep/library/demo/loader.php');
        Loader::register('../lib','RobThree\\Auth');
        use \RobThree\Auth\TwoFactorAuth;

        $tfa = new TwoFactorAuth('Worldhotel.nu');
        $code = $tfa->getCode($secret);

        if(!isset($_SESSION['user']['id'])){
            exit("1");
         }else if(strlen($auth) <= 5 || strlen($auth) >= 7){
             exit("2");
         }else if($tfa->verifyCode($secret, $auth) === true){
             $insertAuth = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET authentication = '1' WHERE id = '".$userdata['id']."' LIMIT 1");
             exit("0");
         }else if($tfa->verifyCode($secret, $auth) === false){
             exit("3");
         }else{
             exit("4");
         }
```

**general.js**

```
  var requestLogin = false;
$(".submit_auth").on("click", function() {
    if(requestLogin == false) {
        requestLogin = true;

        var auth = $('.authcode').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "codemountain/startauth",
            async: true,
            data: {"auth": auth},
            success: function (data) {
                requestLogin = false;

                if (data == "0") {
                    speelWorld.createAlert("Hij klopt. We schakelen Tweestapsverificatie nu in, en herladen je pagina!", "green", 800);
                } else if (data == "1") {
                    speelWorld.createAlert("Je bent ingelogd.", "red", 800);
                } else if (data == "2") {
                     speelWorld.createAlert("Deze code is geen 6 nummers lang.", "red", 800);
                } else if (data == "3") {
                     speelWorld.createAlert("Deze code is niet (meer) geldig. Probeer het opnieuw.", "red", 800);
                 } else {
                     speelWorld.createAlert("Iets gaat hier niet goed. Het spijt ons voor het ongemak.", "red", 800);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Codemountain is rewritten. I've tried the URL without rewriting, but it results in the same. Can't I run this code when posting something with AJAX or am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**
I Found the following error in the logs: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in ajax.php on line 78` which is the following line: `use \RobThree\Auth\TwoFactorAuth;`

Am I including this wrong?

Comment: using something like chrome dev tools (network tab), can you post the results (screen shot) of the AJAX request?

Comment: @phirschybar Yes. http://prntscr.com/dt2b42

Comment: is your POST originating from the same domain?

Comment: @phirschybar Yes. It is.

Comment: If you have ssh access to your server, you can check apache's log and see exactly which is the line that your php script fails.

Comment: @captaintheo I've updated the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `use \RobThree\Auth\TwoFactorAuth;`

That needs to be declared within the outer-most scope of the script: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

I would put that statement right after the opening `<?php` in this script.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks. However, I've tried that. Then another error will show. `PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/authenticator/library/demo/loader.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')`. However, the path is correct. He just can't read it out.

Comment: perhaps move the require statement to the top of the script as well?

Comment: I Did. However, I found the problem following that, we were using a Case. after removing the PHP Switch, it worked. Thanks for your help!